# Programmatically find out maximal work group size supported by openCL device

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu

I'm getting the openCL error `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` with a local work size of 512. The program works with lower powers of 2, so I'm assuming the error cause is exceeding of `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`.

Is there a way to query openCL for that exact value?

Comment: [Very first result on Google for `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/7494-CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE)

Comment: Already found that, thank you! Nowhere in that post it says how to get the attribute.

Comment: No, but it describes what sounds like the same underlying problem that you are experiencing, and suggests both causes and fixes.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I gave it a thorough read and managed to get it working with help of the man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the device's maximum work-group size like this:

```
size_t maxWorkGroupSize;
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,
                sizeof(size_t), &maxWorkGroupSize, NULL);
```

Note that a specific kernel might have a different (lower) maximum, which you can query like this:

```
size_t maxWorkGroupSize;
clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,
                         sizeof(size_t), &maxWorkGroupSize, NULL);
```

Comment: Thx! And here is the related man page: [clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)